# Index a numpy array using a list in a pythonic way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Imagine that I have a python array like

```
array = [[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
```

And a list

```
list = [0,2,1]
```

I basically want a one liner to extract the indexed elements from the array given by the list

For example, with the given array and list:

```
result = [2,7,9]
```

My kneejerk option was

```
result = array[:, list]
```

But that did not work

I know that a for cycle should do it, I just want to know if there is some indexing that might do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
In [24]: a
Out[24]: 
array([[ 2,  3,  4],                                                                              
       [ 5,  6,  7],                                                                              
       [ 8,  9, 10]])                                                                             

In [25]: lis
Out[25]: [0, 2, 1]

In [26]: a[np.arange(len(a)), lis]                                                              
Out[26]: array([2, 7, 9])
```

Comment: Yes, exactly like that, I wonder why would the arange work, but indexing all of them did not.

Comment: @Leonpalafox Check out how indexing on multi-dimensional array works: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` to create row indices and unzip (`zip(*...)`) this collection to get the row indices (the range `[0, len(list))`) and the column indices (`lis`) :

```
a[zip(*enumerate(lis))]
```